# Building SqlExpression throws InvalidOperationException when not using anonymous type in Select() clause

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

This is my database POCO :

```
public class MyPoco1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to select and map results into a custom POCO with different property name :

```
public class MyPocoAlias1
{
    public string OtherName { get; set; }
}

public class MyService : ServiceStack.Service
{
    public List<MyPocoAlias1> Any(MyRequest request)
    {
        // throws InvalidOperationException
        var q1 = Db.From<MyPoco1>().Select(c => new MyPocoAlias1 { OtherName = c.Name });

        // this works
        var q2 = Db.From<MyPoco1>().Select(c => new { OtherName = c.Name });
        var items = Db.Select<MyPocoAlias1>(q2);

        return items;
    }
}
```

q1 fails with a System.InvalidOperationException :

> "variable 'c' of type 'MyPoco1' referenced from scope '', but it is
>   not defined".

q2 works, but is there a way to do this with a strong type (which check correct property names/types) or is this mandatory to use an anonymous type in the .Select() clause ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of `.Select()` in a Typed OrmLite SqlExpression is to specify which fields should be specified in the SELECT expression. Which you can use to select a single field, e.g:

```
var q = db.From<Table>().Select(x => x.Name);
```

Multiple fields:

```
var q = db.From<Table>().Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Name });
```

Or fields with aliases:

```
var q = db.From<Table>().Select(x => new { x.Id, OtherName = x.Name });
```

It's not for specifying which model it should project to, that happens when you execute the query, e.g:

```
var results = db.Select<MyPocoAlias1>(q);
```

Which will map the returned result set (e.g. SELECT Id, Name AS "OtherName") into the `MyPocoAlias1` POCO.

Answer (score 1):

in your code

> var q1 = Db.From()
>       .Select(c => new MyPocoAlias1 { OtherName = c.Name })

This is the way we use anonymous types. delete your class `MyPocoAlias1` because it is not needed. You have used anonymous type but you have named it. change that to

```
var q1 = Db.From<MyPoco1>()
    .Select(c => new { OtherName = c.Name })
```

And instead of OtherName you can use anything you want.

Comment: Like q2 in my example ?
So it's not possible to use a class in the Select() ?

Comment: you can use anonymous class which does the job, Its much more easier. and lets you name it what ever you want. but it is possible to use a class. you should use lambda expresion. do you know about them?

Comment: I can't name it what ever I want because I must map the result into a `MyPocoAlias1`. I know a little about lambda expressions, but I can't see what's wrong in my code (and I don't understand the exception details), isn't that `c => new MyPocoAlias1 { OtherName = c.Name }` a valid lambda ?

Comment: @AdamBross of course it is valid but as I focused now, the problem is with `var q1 = Db.From<MyPoco1>()
    .Select(c => new MyPocoAlias1 { OtherName = c.Name });`. the problem is that for `From` you have specified `MyPoco1` but in the select you have selected `MyPocoAlias1`

Comment: Same exception if I use `var q1 = Db.From<MyPoco1>().Select(c => new MyPoco1 { Name = c.Name });` , however the types in From() and Select() are the same

Comment: @AdamBross how did you instantiate Db?

Comment: I have edited my example. I don't directly instantiate Db, this is a property of the ServiceStack Service class initialized by IoC in my AppHost.

Comment: have you tried that without using From? I can not see what Db contains

Comment: because I do not have your Db I can not test it in my visual studio, but for final try I can suggest you bring a constructor with one string argument and in the select, use `new new MyPocoAlias1(c.Name)`